# syntax error in access when using iif in query expression

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to create a Query based on an evaluation of an empty field.

```
Item: [Huis] & IIf(IsNull([Naam]), "", " / " & [Naam])  & IIf(IsNull([Druif]), "", " / " & [Druif]) & iif(IsNull([Type]), "", " / " & [Type])
```

It gives me a syntax error: Missing an operand or operator, you have entered an invalid character or comma or you have not enclosed the text in the expression in quotation marks.

I have tried other examples that are supposed to work here on stackoverflow, they all give the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the SQL view of query. This seems to come from design view. Right now, I do not see comma or parentheses issues so it may be these table values if they exist or not.

Comment: what version of access? try to use semi colon instead of comma in iif function.

Comment: Access 2016, I indeed entered the expression in Design Mode, but I don't see why it could be wrong. Still have to find my way around a little, got me really demotivated.

Comment: Using a semi colon also did the trick, thanks for your reply!

Comment: In SQL view, the comma is always correct. But in Design view, with German and (apparently) French locale settings, semicolon is the function argument separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see an error either, but you can simplify your expression by taking advantage of the fact that `&` concatenates NULL values, but `+` doesn't.

```
Item: [Huis] & (" / " + [Naam]) & (" / " + [Druif]) & (" / " + [Type])
```

Each block, e.g. `(" / " + [Naam])` will be NULL if the field is NULL.